# What is the preferred way of specifying a transformer for the response of an outgoing gateway using DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following piece of code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ISOGatewayProperties::class)
class ISOGatewayConfig {

    @Bean
    fun isoGatewayFlow(
        isoProps: ISOGatewayProperties,
        isoTransformer: ISOTransformer) : IntegrationFlow =
            IntegrationFlows
                .from(MessageChannels.direct("isoInChannel"))
                .log()
                .transform(isoTransformer)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(
                    Tcp.netClient(isoProps.host, isoProps.port)))
                .get()
}
```

This code correctly converts the request which is an object to a byte[] for sending to the remote server

My questions are the following:

1. What is the preferred way of transforming the response from the server?
2. Is it possible to use a single class for both transformations?

Answered by Artem
The correct way of doing custom protocols is to use custom serializer/deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `.transform(...)` after that `.handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(...))` in the flow.

Well, you can use the same class for both request and response, but I believe in case of response you need to create an ISO object from the `byte[]`, therefore you would need to specify a method name as a second `.transform()` argument to make things clear for the target transformation endpoint.

Comment: I tried that, I can see the remote sending the response, but the client times out reading it.  I also tried using a serializer and deserializer with the serializing flushing the data.  Get the same result there.  BTW.  This flow is being called from a MessageGateway that has a return value.

Comment: OK. So, so you need to configure a `Tcp.netClient()` with an appropriate (de)serializer for the proper TCP packages delimiter. By default it uses `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` expecting a `\r\n` symbols in the end of each message. So, you need to consul with your ISO provider to determine what is the delimiter should be used for the proper communication. Or they may expect from your some other way to distinguish package, e.g. `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer`. Please, consult Docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-connection-factories